# MS-Access combobox adding record to table that is supposed to be a lookup

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a form with subforms that has been created from a query that I created. This query has information from 6 tables. The form is separated into basically 3 sections.

The main form is Credit Union information, first subform is Branch information and the second subform is Circuit information based on the branch record that is selected. In the Branch subform I have a combobox that is set up to display the TimeZones table info so that when creating a new branch in the form you can automatically select the timezone.

The issue I am having is that when I select the timezone and save the record, a new record is created in the Time zone table with the same text information just a different ID, rather then what I expect it to do which is add the existing time zone ID to the new branch record.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it sounds like you are hoping to use information from the time zone table to add the field "timezone" to your Branch table. If I'm correct, you would have to add that field to your Branch table in design view first. Then, you go to your combobox properties within your form. Next to row source, type "SELECT [TimeZones].[timezone] FROM [TimeZones] - making sure of course the spelling matches the tables/fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input but I was able to figure it out. Instead of keeping the "Time Zone" field on the Brnaches table as a text input or matching the Timezone ID from the Time Zone table, I changed the Brnaches table "TimeZone" field to be a lookup field that queried the Timzone table before the information was added to a Form. Then when the form was created, the timezone entry was already a combobox and already queried the Timzone Table.